# sqlite log about creation a database

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is my code to create the database, but it does not work and I don't know why.

```
public class DBAdapter {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Enquete15";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private static final String MENAGE = "table_MENAGE";

    private static final String _id = "Numero_du_Questionnaire";
    private static final String col_Code_district = "Code_district";
    private static final String col_Region= "region";
    private static final String col_Provence_prefecture  = "provence_prefecture";
    private static final String col_Commune_Arrondissement  = "Commune_Arrondissement ";
    private static final String col_N_district  = "Numero_district ";
    private static final String col_N_M_district = "N_ménage_district ";
    private static final String col_N_menage_logement  = "N_menage_logement ";
    private static final String col_Adresse_menage = "Adresse_menage";
    private static final String col_Nom_Enqueteur = "Nom_enqueteur";
    private static final String col_code_enquêteur  = "code_enqueteur ";
    private static final String col_Date_realisation_enquête  = "Date_réalisation_enquête ";
    private static final String col_Nom_controleur  = "Nom_contrôleur ";
    private static final String col_code_controleur  = "code_contrôleur ";
    private static final String col_Date_controle  = "Date_contrôle ";
    private static final String col_echantillon_principal  = "echantillon_principal";
    private static final String col_Statut_enquêté  = "Statut_enquêté ";
    private static final String col_Observations   = "Observations ";
    private static final String col_Type_habitat   = "Type_habitat";
    private static final String col_Statut_occupation   = "Statut_occupation ";
    private static final String col_Nombre_ménages_habitant_logement   = "Nombre_ménages_habitant_logement ";
    private static final String col_Nombre_pièces_occupes_ménage   = "Nombre_pièces_occupés_ménage ";
    private static final String col_Mode_principal_approvisionnement_eau_potable    = "Mode_principal_approvisionnement_eau_potable  ";
    private static final String col_Mode_principal_éclairage    = "Mode_principal_éclairage ";
    private static final String col_Mode_principal_assainissement   = "Mode_principal_assainissement  ";
    private static final String col_Disposition_local_cuisine   = "Disposition_local_cuisine ";
    private static final String col_Disposition_local_WC = "Disposition_local_WC ";
    private static final String col_Disposition_salle_eau = "Disposition_salle_eau(douche_baignoire)  ";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + MENAGE + "(" + _id +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + col_Region +" TEXT,"+  col_Provence_prefecture +" TEXT,"
    + col_Commune_Arrondissement +" TEXT,"+ col_N_district +" INT,"
    + col_N_M_district +" INT,"+ col_N_menage_logement +" INT,"+ col_Adresse_menage + " INT," 
    + col_Nom_Enqueteur +" INT,"+ col_code_enquêteur +" INT,"+ col_Date_realisation_enquête +" INT,"+ col_Nom_controleur +" INT,"+ col_code_controleur +" INT,"+ col_Date_controle +" INT,"+ col_echantillon_principal +" INT,"+ col_Statut_enquêté +" INT,"+ col_Observations +" INT,"+ col_Type_habitat +" INT,"+ col_Statut_occupation +" INT,"+ col_Nombre_ménages_habitant_logement +" INT,"
    + col_Nombre_pièces_occupes_ménage +" INT,"+ col_Mode_principal_approvisionnement_eau_potable +" INT,"
    + col_Mode_principal_éclairage +" INT,"+ col_Mode_principal_assainissement +" INT,"
    + col_Disposition_local_cuisine +" INT,"+ col_Disposition_local_WC +" INT,"
    + col_Disposition_salle_eau + " INT,"+ col_Disposition_local_WC +" INT" + ")";
```

The LogCat shows a syntax error near "(".

Comment: Post your logcat if there is an error, your DB contract (the table name and columns) and explain what "did not work". We cannot try to guess all the possibilities of issue. My guess now is: 1. it tries to create an existing table, or 2. wrong use of `_id`.

Comment: thanks for responding, the logcat indicates a sqlite log (1) near "(": syntax error. i tried many times but it didn't work. thanks again

Comment: it would be great if someone has an idea how to solve the problem, i already looked for a solution by trying many possibilities but it's just don't work !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the error was caused by having parentheses in one of your column:

```
private static final String col_Disposition_salle_eau = "Disposition_salle_eau(douche_baignoire)  ";
```

Remove and avoid parentheses for table and column names.

Also, there is a duplicated column name:

```
+ col_Disposition_local_WC +" INT,"
+ col_Disposition_salle_eau + " INT,"
+ col_Disposition_local_WC +" INT" + ")"; // duplicate
```

Remove one of it.

Comment: well it did work, i appreciate your efforts, but i didn't know about parentheses for table and column names ! thanks a lot.